# Linking multiple lists in flask

Tags: python, list, flask

I'm trying to create a flask project that displays certain details depending on which team you select. For example, if I click on Chelsea who are the 4th team on the list, I would like the fourth badge, manager, stadium, capacity and nickname to appear, but I'm not sure how to do this.

(At the moment I just have it outputting the first thing in each list just for something to appear on the screen)

football.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('football.html')

@app.route('/bpl/')
def bplLink():
  teamName = ['AFC Bournemouth', 'Arsenal', 'Aston Villa', 'Chelsea',
  'Crystal Palace', 'Everton', 'Leicester City', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester City',
  'Manchester United', 'Newcastle United', 'Norwich City', 'Southampton',
  'Stoke City', 'Sunderland', 'Swansea City', 'Tottenham Hotspur',
  'Watford', 'West Bromwich Albion', 'West Ham United']
  return render_template('bplteams.html', teamName=teamName)

@app.route('/bpl/<team>')
def team(team):
  stadium = ['Dean Court', 'Emirates Stadium', 'Villa Park', 'Stamford Bridge',
  'Selhurst Park', 'Goodison Park', 'King Power Stadium', 'Anfield',
  'Etihad Stadium', 'Old Trafford', 'St James Park', 'Carrow Road',
  'St Marys Stadium', 'Britannia Stadium', 'Stadium of Light',
  'Liberty Stadium', 'White Hart Lane', 'Vicarage Road', 'The Hawthorns',
  'Boleyn Ground']
  badge = ['bournemouth.png', 'arsenal.png', 'aston-villa.png', 'chelsea.png',
  'crystal-palace.png', 'everton.png', 'leicester.png', 'liverpool',
  'man-city.png', 'man-united.png', 'newcastle.png', 'norwich.png',
  'southampton.png', 'stoke.png', 'sunderland.png', 'swansea.png',
  'tottenham.png', 'watford.png', 'west-brom.png', 'west-ham.png']
  capacity = ['11,464', '60,260', '42,660', '41,798', '25,073', '39,571',
  '32,312', '44,742', '55,097', '75,653', '52,338', '27,010', '32,505',
  '27,740', '48,707', '20,909', '36,284', '21,500', '26,850', '35,345']
  manager = ['Eddie Howe', 'Arsene Wenger', 'Kevin MacDonald (caretaker)',
  'Jose Mourinho', 'Alan Pardew', 'Roberto Martinez', 'Claudio Ranieri',
  'Jurgen Klopp', 'Manuel Pellegrini', 'Louis van Gaal', 'Steve McClaren',
  'Alex Neil', 'Ronald Koeman', 'Mark Hughes', 'Sam Allardyce', 'Garry Monk',
  'Mauricio Pochettino', 'Quique Flores', 'Tony Pulis', 'Slaven Bilic']
  nickname = ['Cherries', 'Gunners', 'Villans', 'Blues', 'Eagles', 'Toffees',
  'Foxes', 'Reds', 'City', 'Red Devils', 'Magpies', 'Canaries', 'Saints',
  'Potters', 'Black Cats', 'Swans', 'Spurs', 'Hornets', 'Baggies', 'Irons']
  return render_template('details.html', team=team, stadium=stadium,
  badge=badge, capacity=capacity, manager=manager, nickname=nickname)
```

bplteams.html  (lists all of the teams)

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
{% for team in teamName %}
  <a href="/bpl/{{team}}">{{team}}</a><br />
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

details.html (team details)

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<h1>{{ team }}</h1>
<img src="/static/{{ badge[0] }}">
<p>Nickname: {{ nickname[0] }}</p>
<p>Manager: {{ manager[0] }}</p>
<p>Stadium: {{ stadium[0] }}</p>
<p>Capacity: {{ capacity[0] }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should use array indexing in `team` function?

Comment: Do you mean like how I've done with the other lists? Sorry if that's stupid, I'm a beginner to python flask!

Comment: No, you should return the right value from `team` function, returning for example `stadium[team]` or `manager[team]` or all at the same time or return a complex object.

Comment: So would I want something like 

{'name': 'AFC Bournemouth', 'badge': 'bournemouth.png', 'stadium': 'Dean Court', 'capacity': '11,464', 'manager': 'Eddie Howe', 'nickname': 'Cherries'},

and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the index to `team` route. Here is the final solution.

`football.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('football.html')

@app.route('/bpl/')
def bplLink():
  teamName = ['AFC Bournemouth', 'Arsenal', 'Aston Villa', 'Chelsea',
  'Crystal Palace', 'Everton', 'Leicester City', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester City',
  'Manchester United', 'Newcastle United', 'Norwich City', 'Southampton',
  'Stoke City', 'Sunderland', 'Swansea City', 'Tottenham Hotspur',
  'Watford', 'West Bromwich Albion', 'West Ham United']
  return render_template('bplteams.html', teamName=teamName)

@app.route('/bpl/<team>')
def team(team):
  index = int(request.args.get('index', 0))
  stadium = ['Dean Court', 'Emirates Stadium', 'Villa Park', 'Stamford Bridge',
  'Selhurst Park', 'Goodison Park', 'King Power Stadium', 'Anfield',
  'Etihad Stadium', 'Old Trafford', 'St James Park', 'Carrow Road',
  'St Marys Stadium', 'Britannia Stadium', 'Stadium of Light',
  'Liberty Stadium', 'White Hart Lane', 'Vicarage Road', 'The Hawthorns',
  'Boleyn Ground']
  badge = ['bournemouth.png', 'arsenal.png', 'aston-villa.png', 'chelsea.png',
  'crystal-palace.png', 'everton.png', 'leicester.png', 'liverpool',
  'man-city.png', 'man-united.png', 'newcastle.png', 'norwich.png',
  'southampton.png', 'stoke.png', 'sunderland.png', 'swansea.png',
  'tottenham.png', 'watford.png', 'west-brom.png', 'west-ham.png']
  capacity = ['11,464', '60,260', '42,660', '41,798', '25,073', '39,571',
  '32,312', '44,742', '55,097', '75,653', '52,338', '27,010', '32,505',
  '27,740', '48,707', '20,909', '36,284', '21,500', '26,850', '35,345']
  manager = ['Eddie Howe', 'Arsene Wenger', 'Kevin MacDonald (caretaker)',
  'Jose Mourinho', 'Alan Pardew', 'Roberto Martinez', 'Claudio Ranieri',
  'Jurgen Klopp', 'Manuel Pellegrini', 'Louis van Gaal', 'Steve McClaren',
  'Alex Neil', 'Ronald Koeman', 'Mark Hughes', 'Sam Allardyce', 'Garry Monk',
  'Mauricio Pochettino', 'Quique Flores', 'Tony Pulis', 'Slaven Bilic']
  nickname = ['Cherries', 'Gunners', 'Villans', 'Blues', 'Eagles', 'Toffees',
  'Foxes', 'Reds', 'City', 'Red Devils', 'Magpies', 'Canaries', 'Saints',
  'Potters', 'Black Cats', 'Swans', 'Spurs', 'Hornets', 'Baggies', 'Irons']
  return render_template('details.html', team=team, stadium=stadium,
                         badge=badge, capacity=capacity, manager=manager,
                         nickname=nickname, index=index)
```

`bplteams.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
{% for team in teamName %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('team', team=team, index=loop.index0) }}">{{team}}</a><br />
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

`details.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<h1>{{ team }}</h1>
<img src="/static/{{ badge[index] }}">
<p>Nickname: {{ nickname[index] }}</p>
<p>Manager: {{ manager[index] }}</p>
<p>Stadium: {{ stadium[index] }}</p>
<p>Capacity: {{ capacity[index] }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's solved it for me, thank you very much for your help! Really appreciate it!